# PowerShell Get-WinEvent Display only first line of Message property?

Tags: powershell, parsing

Getting acquinted with PowerShell, running into myriads of problems (lack of knowledge).

I'm trying to list myself Windows Security Log logged events by count, but I could also use a "friendly" description field which happens to be the first line of the "Message" Property. I can't figure out a way to extract only that.

Thus, I'm running the following to get an overview of events:

```
PS C:\TEST> Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="security"}| Group-Object id -NoElement | sort count

Count Name
----- ----
    1 4724
    1 4722
    1 1102
    1 4725
    2 4718
    2 6408
    2 4739
    2 1101
    2 5038
    2 4737
    3 4717
    4 6407
    4 4731
   10 4738
   16 1100
   19 4781
   22 4904
   22 4905
   35 6406
   38 5033
   38 5024
   39 4826
   39 4608
   39 4902
   40 4735
  113 4647
  156 4616
  239 5059
  355 4688
  551 4733
  557 4732
  605 4797
  965 5061
  977 5058
 1647 4798
 6364 4907
 6759 4634
 7000 4648
10950 4799
19407 4672
22049 4624
```

But what I want is to include the "Description/Message" Column to show what each event ID corresponds to. For example, for event ID the `Message` Property contains the following value(?):

```
An attempt was made to reset an account's password.

    Subject:
            Security ID:            S-1-5-18
            Account Name:           [EDITED]
            Account Domain:         [EDITED]
            Logon ID:               0x3E7

    Target Account:
            Security ID:            [EDITED]
            Account Name:           Administrator
            Account Domain:         [EDITED]
```

Out of this entire Message I'd wish to extract only the following line:

```
An attempt was made to reset an account's password.
```

Thus getting back to my original view, ideally it would show the following:

```
Count Name Message
----- ---- ----
    1 4724 An attempt was made to reset an account's password.
    1 4722 A user account was enabled.
    1 1102 The audit log was cleared.
(...)
```

Comment: So you'll have to iterate the groups with a foreach, get the message from the first element of the group, split it at `"`r?`n"` and only output the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="security"} | Group-Object id

$Events | Select-Object Count,Name,@{Name='Message';Expression={ (($_.Group.Message | Select -First 1) -Split "`n")[0] }} | Sort-Object Count -Descending | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Works by removing the `-NoElement` parameter of `Group-Object` so that we get the `Group` result returned, which we can then retrieve the first line of the message property from.

We use `Select-Object` to add a calculated property to the result that contains the message.

Also using `Format-Table -Wrap` so the view of the final output doesn't truncate the first line if its long.

Example output:

```
Count Name Message                                         
----- ---- -------                                         
   81 4798 A user's local group membership was enumerated. 
   13 5379 Credential Manager credentials were read.       
    5 5061 Cryptographic operation.                        
    1 5058 Key file operation.
```

Comment: This is gold!
I need to understand better the expression part `(($_.Group.Message | Select -First 1) -Split "`n")[0]`
Your selecting for each object `$_` the `Group.Message` property, then afterwars you `select` the first object(?) and `split` it based on newline, rigth?
What's the `[0]` doing? I assume it's selecting the 1st line (starting from 0)?

I will have follow up questions, ideally I'd like to split the entire `message` property based on its contents like a key/value object for each event id...

Comment: Yeah, because `Group.Message` would be an array of messages from all of the events in that group, we use `Select -First 1` to just get the first. Then the `-split` operator is returning an array of strings, so we use `[0]` to return the first element of that array (arrays count from 0).

Comment: I don't want to abuse you too much, but could you maybe point me towards a learning place that could explain this tome (I've been googling since morning, inefficiently apparently)? Let's say I wish to know how to break down the `Message` into an array(?) or hastable(?) and build questions around the property/value or key/value pairs?

Comment: You can use `Get-Member` to explore the properties of objects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/viewing-object-structure--get-member-?view=powershell-6
Sometimes it's useful also to just pipe an object to `Fomat-List *` to get a view of all properties and their contents (at least at the first level). Try `$_ | Format-List *`

Comment: KevMar does very good deep dives. Try this: https://powershellexplained.com/2017-04-10-Powershell-exceptions-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know/

Comment: Again, thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to find & understand (coming from bash, where stuff wasn't an object)! I couldn't figure out how to list the properties available to me, now I know from here: https://powershellexplained.com/2018-10-15-Powershell-arrays-Everything-you-wanted-to-know
I can break down the events by: `$event4672 = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="security";id=4672} -MaxEvents 1` and `$event4672 | gm -MemberType Properties` and finally `$event4672.Properties` thus I now understand where do the values for indexes come from `$event4672.Properties[0]`.